# Make paragraph text fill container

Tags: css, layout

I've seen a property that allow you to fill the entire width of a container with text, ala magazine style. It simply increases the space between words to accommodate for the additional space.

What is this property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're thinking of `text-align: justify`.

```css
div {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nec nisl ipsum, at ullamcorper justo. Vivamus ac dui lorem. Aliquam nec diam urna, in semper augue. Etiam commodo dui velit. Vestibulum in nibh nulla, a feugiat justo. Proin accumsan, tellus et condimentum laoreet, lacus lorem consequat nisi, ac fermentum velit eros at metus. Aliquam lacinia mollis felis, vel pretium nulla condimentum consectetur. Quisque in mattis nibh. Nunc adipiscing tincidunt elit, vitae pellentesque felis molestie ac. Fusce vestibulum dui in nibh gravida ut placerat ligula porta. Ut sem lectus, condimentum nec tincidunt a, imperdiet vitae risus.</div>
```